# How to detect TAB key-press in JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, key-bindings

I am trying to find out how to detect if a JComboBox lost focus when user pressed tab or via a mouse-click outside the component's area.

Adding a FocusListener to the editor component of the JComboBox does not help me, as I can't find out if user used the mouse or moved the focus via the tab key. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:
What I am trying to achieve is this:

- Suppose user drops down the list (JComboBox popupMenu shows up), and navigates via cursor keys...
- Case 1: user presses tab. In this case, I want to cut off some of the information from the item and show only some parts.
- Case 2: user clicks with the mouse outside the popupMenu's area (here we have subcases, but they all fall into the same category). In this case I want to change JComboBox to show the previously edited item, not what user navigated...
- There are several other cases (mouse item pick, the enter key, escape, etc.). I could easily handle these, but detecting tab is tricky because I can't catch this event as it is handled by FocusManager.

Edit 2:
It seems that I have to use `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)` to get notified when TAB is pressed, and when i capture that event, I should manually transfer focus... I do not like this solution, but that is so far the best I could come up with.

Solution:

Following piece of Java code is actually solving my problem. As I wrote in *Edit 2* the easiest solution was to disable focus traversal. I shamelessly borrowed Kleopatra's code, and all works now. :)

```
    if (!isTableCellEditor()) {
        comboBoxEditor.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        Action myAction = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                handleTabPress();
                comboBoxEditor.transferFocus();
            } // actionPerformed() method
        };

        comboBoxEditor.getActionMap().put("tab-action", myAction);
        comboBoxEditor.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
            .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "tab-action");
    } // if
```

Thanks to all participants in the discussion!

Comment: *"Any ideas would be greatly appreciated."*  Explain the use-case for this functionality.  What feature are you trying to offer the end user by knowing?

Comment: Andrew, thanks for reply, see the *Edit 1*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand your question, there are two separate problems

- don't commit the value while navigating
- take over the reaction to TAB

if so, the answers are

- configure the combo so that it thinks it is the editing component of a CellEditor
- disable the default traversal keys for the combo and take over with a custom binding

In code:

```
    final JComboBox simpleBox = new JComboBox(Locale.getAvailableLocales());
    // this line configures the combo to only commit on ENTER 
    // or selecting an item from the list
    simpleBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
    //
    // simpleBox.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
    //     Collections.EMPTY_SET);
    // just noticed the OPs edit - following indeed is easier to disable _all_ traversal
    // keys with one statement
    simpleBox.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    Action myAction = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LOG.info("got it!");
            simpleBox.transferFocus();
        }

    };
    simpleBox.getActionMap().put("tab-action", myAction);
    simpleBox.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
       .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "tab-action");
```

Comment: Thanks Kleopatra, finally someone who understands the problem... When my combo-box is in  a form (not a cell-editor), i do not commit anything. It is all automatic. As you probably know, setSelectedItem() is called automatically when you navigate. So, what I do is - when user presses ENTER, or uses the mouse to pick an item, i store that, so i know what item is actually picked. (That is equal to non-commit, because i always show the latest PICKED item). I can't set it to believe it is a cell editor, because I have separate logic when it is a cell-editor... :(

Comment: if you take a look at my *Edit 2*, you'll see what I am trying to do now... That seems the easiest solution. What you think?

Comment: probably dont understand what you are after ;-) Setting the client property makes the combo behave as you describe your requirement, IMO: the user can navigate without commiting (aka: selecting to the combo) the item selected in the drop-down list. If s/he wants to commit, s/he has do so actively - either by pressing ENTER or by a mouseClick into the drop-down. Nothing else to code for the "click-away" case

Comment: If i do not have separate logic for the case when my combo-box is a cell-editor or for the case when it is not, then `JTable.isCellEditor` client property would do exactly what I want. But unfortunately that would break the logic i have in case when it is not a cell-editor... :( So I either refactor that, or disable focus traversal and capture TAB...

Comment: refactor - because for me it sounds like you are on the wrong track, wildly guessing, of course, without seeing any details :-) How about a sscce to describe exactly what you need and why you think you cant use the approach above?

Answer (score 3):

It is assumed that you have pressed the mouse (or key) right before you loose focus. So listen to all the keyboard and mouse clicks, and the one used last right before loosing focus is the culprit.

When focuslost is fired, you would check a variable you set when a mouse or key is pressed, on any part of your window. This variable just logs the last mouse and/or key pressed. You would have to capture all the mouse and keypresses of course, since clicking on any widget would let you loose focus.

Comment: FocusLost is fired anyway, and I can't find out if it was fired when user pressed TAB, or when user clicked somewhere ... That is the essence of the question.

Comment: Yes, so when focuslost is fired, you would check a variable you set when a mouse or key is pressed, on any part of your window. This variable just logs the last mouse and/or key pressed. You would have to capture *all* the mouse and keypresses of course, since clicking on any widget would let you loose focus.

Comment: That does not help, because when TAB is pressed, KeyListener does nothing... If KeyListener worked with TAB I would not ask this question at all... :)

Comment: PS, i get your point, but tracking down mouse events is useless if i can't detect focus-lost with the TAB key. And if I could get the TAB key, i do not need mouse events at all (the rest are all mouse events anyway because they are the only ones not covered). See *Edit 2*.