# How to accept a value in a Swing JComboBox with the Tab key

Tags: java, swing, focus, jcombobox, keylistener

How do you get a Java combobox to accept the highlighted value when you type the Tab key, like it does when you type Enter?
I think of this as a UI norm, and have seen it on websites and desktop programs, so I don't understand why Java doesn't do it by default.  (The escape key is there to cancel.)

I found several related questions to this, including how to get Enter to behave like Tab, but it turned out harder to go the other way, so I'll post how I did it.  Perhaps I missed an easy way!

In particular, [the closest posting I could find](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1363407?start=0&tstart=0) didn't work because the tab key was already consumed by the focus system.
Other related questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889744/make-enter-key-act-like-a-tab-key-for-jtextfield-jcombobox-jspinner-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249728/how-to-detect-tab-key-press-in-jcombobox?rq=1), and maybe some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042429/how-can-i-modify-the-behavior-of-the-tab-key-in-a-jtextarea/5043957#5043957).

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because of how inaccessible the Enter-key handling is.  It takes place in a big if-else tree in `BasicComboBoxUI.actionPerformed()`.  This is where it pulls the value into the combobox from the also-inaccessible popup menu.  It's also tricky because focus-traversal key events are consumed before you can do anything with them.

To get this to work, I had to remove Tab from the set of focus-traversal keys, override `processKeyEvent()` on the JComboBox, and *sorry!* pass a fake Enter-key event to the superclass, in order to let the UI do what it normally does for Enter.  Then I had to handle the focus transitions manually.

Here's some code.  (I handled shift-tab/backwards focus traversals the same way, which was probably overkill.)

```
protected final JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox() {
    @Override
    public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {           
        if ( e.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
                || e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            super.processKeyEvent(e);
            return;
        }

        if (isPopupVisible()) {
            assert e.getSource() instanceof Component;
            KeyEvent fakeEnterKeyEvent = new KeyEvent((Component) e.getSource(),
                    e.getID(),
                    e.getWhen(),
                    0,                   // No modifiers.
                    KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,   // Enter key.
                    KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED);
            super.processKeyEvent(fakeEnterKeyEvent);
        }
        if ( e.getModifiers() == 0) {
            transferFocus();
        } else if ( e.getModifiers() == KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) {
            transferFocusBackward();
        }
    }
};

// Remove tabs from focus traversal keylists.
// Forward.
Set<AWTKeyStroke> focuskeys = Sets.newHashSet(combobox.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
KeyStroke lTabKeystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed TAB");
focuskeys.remove(lTabKeystroke);
combobox.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, focuskeys);
// Backward.
focuskeys = Sets.newHashSet(combobox.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
KeyStroke lShiftTabKeystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift pressed TAB");
focuskeys.remove(lShiftTabKeystroke);
combobox.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, focuskeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swing uses Key Bindings to invoke Actions for different KeyStrokes. JComboBox has an Action for the ENTER key. See the list of all the bindings at [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

So I thought it would be a simple case of binding the ENTER Action to another KeyStroke.

Sure enough, when I bound the ENTER Action to the `RIGHT` arrow key the functionality worked as expected.

However, when I bound the Enter Action to the `TAB` key it did not work. However, the popup menu is still closed. So now I'm wondering if the TAB key is handled by another component to close the menu which is preventing the new TAB key binding from working. Maybe someone else has insight into this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxTest2 extends JFrame
{
    JComboBox comboBox;
    JTextField textField;
    String[] tabs;
    public ComboBoxTest2()
    {
        String[] tabs = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };

        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(tabs);
        comboBox = new JComboBox( model );
        add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add( new JButton("A Component To Tab To"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //  This works

        InputMap im = comboBox.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        KeyStroke existingKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
        KeyStroke rightKS = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
        im.put(rightKS, im.get(existingKeyStroke));

        //  This doesn't work

        comboBox.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        KeyStroke tabKS = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB");
        im.put(tabKS, im.get(existingKeyStroke));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxTest2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the follow-up!  One thing I didn't mention: I actually got null for im.get(ENTER) when I tried your soln.  I see the difference, though: I used WHEN_FOCUSED to get the input map, rather than WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF.  I tried WHEN_ANCESTOR now and did see the non-null binding.  Like you reported here, though, setting that same binding for TAB doesn't work.  (One more note: I think Tab and Enter should behave differently in the case when the popup is not showing.  I think only tab should advance the focus to the next component in that case.)